error: '__device_dts_ord_DT_N_ALIAS_stepper' undeclared here (not in a function)
I am writting a code in zephyr RTOS for stm32 nulceo h7a3zi_q, to control 3 stepper motors. Now I am getting the following error while doing west build :
error: '__device_dts_ord_DT_N_ALIAS_stepper' undeclared here (not in a function)

this is a part of the overlay file where the steppers are defined :
    aliases {
            debug-uart = &usart2;
            mother-uart = &usart6;
            stepper-motor1 = &stepper_motor_1; 
            stepper-motor2 = &stepper_motor_2; 
            stepper-motor3 = &stepper_motor_3; 
    };
   

    steppermotors { 
        compatible = "stepper-motors"; 
        stepper_motor_1: motor_1 { 
            label = "First link"; 
            dir-gpios = <&gpioa 3 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>; //A0
            step-gpios = <&gpioc 0 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>; //A1
        };
    
        stepper_motor_2: motor_2 {
            label = "Second Link"; 
            dir-gpios = <&gpioc 3 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>; //A2
            step-gpios = <&gpiob 1 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>; //A3
        };
    
        stepper_motor_3: motor_3 { 
            label = "Turn Table";
            dir-gpios = <&gpioc 2 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>; //A4
            step-gpios = <&gpiof 7 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>; //A5
        };
    };
};

The binding used by the steppermotors node :
description: Stepper motors driven by TB6600 (parent node)

compatible: "stepper-motors"

child-binding:
  description: GPIO-driven dc motor (child node)
  properties:
    dir-gpios:
      required: true
      type: phandle-array
      description: |
        Dir pin for the motor

    step-gpios:
      required: true
      type: phandle-array
      description: |
        Step pin for the motor

    label:
      type: string
      description: |
        Human readable string describing the motor.

this is the prj.conf :
CONFIG_GPIO=y
CONFIG_PRINTK=y
CONFIG_LOG=y
CONFIG_LOG_PRINTK=y
CONFIG_SERIAL=y
CONFIG_I2C=y
CONFIG_SENSOR=y
CONFIG_MPU6050=y
CONFIG_MPU6050_TRIGGER_NONE=y
CONFIG_UART_INTERRUPT_DRIVEN=y
CONFIG_PWM=y
CONFIG_CRC=y
CONFIG_USB_CDC_ACM=y
CONFIG_KYVERNITIS=y
CONFIG_CANSCRIBE=y
CONFIG_CANARD=y
CONFIG_Tarzan=y

CONFIG_CBPRINTF_FP_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_REBOOT=y

CONFIG_USB_DEVICE_STACK=y
CONFIG_USB_DEVICE_PRODUCT="Team RUDRA Tarzan"
CONFIG_USB_DEVICE_PID=0x0004
CONFIG_USB_DEVICE_INITIALIZE_AT_BOOT=n

CONFIG_SERIAL=y
CONFIG_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_UART_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_UART_LINE_CTRL=y

How do I solve this issue?
I think I am missing some configurations in prj.conf.
How can I solve this issue, I tired putting some additional configurations in prj.conf, but that didnt help as well.

it looks like you try to get you stepper using DT_ALIAS(stepper) but  you don't have a stepper= alias
